# Add moving overlay on video with ffmpeg

Tags: animation, ffmpeg, overlay

I need to have an overlay move on a video as a function of time.

[image: FFMPEG moving image]
I am using this to change the `y` coordinate of the overlay.

```
y='if(gte(t,0.5), ((H/2)-h-t*65), NAN)
```

How do I get the y coordinate to stop after a few seconds, i.e at 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Clamp the `t` variable input

```
y='if(gte(t,0.5), ((H/2)-h-min(t\,3)*65), NAN)
```